# Error: model item passed into dictionary is of type 'ContactWeb.Models.RoleListViewModel', but dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having trouble with this line of code: `@{Html.RenderPartial("Form", Model.Contact);}`
This is the error I'm getting:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ContactWeb.Models.RoleListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ContactWebLibrary.Contact'.

I have RoleListViewModel listed at the top of the view and I have Contact property in my RoleListViewModel so I'm not sure why it's complaining. Can anyone please help me to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just leave out passing a model to the partial view, strongly type the partial view to the same model as the view, and then use the models parameters? Since the model is being passed into the view, any partial view should automatically have access to a parent views model data.

Comment: What is your contact properties type in your model? Also why are you enclosing it in {} you shouldn't need that.

Comment: in the rolelistviewmodel, I have created property public Contact Contact {get;set;}. I thought for renderpartial I need the braces. The edit view is using a form that uses ContactWebLibrary.Contact as its model.

Answer (score 3):

As a third parameter, you need to pass in a new ViewDataDictionary.

Comment: Like this?: @{Html.RenderPartial("Form", Model.Contact, new ViewDataDictionary());} I'm getting an error on the Form now...

Comment: Yeah, or it may require a ViewDataDictionary<ContactType>. You don't need the { } surrounding the call, though.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the Form when I add the new ViewDataDictionary.

Comment: In the Form, on the line <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" />, it is giving a NullReferenceException that the object reference is not set to the instance of an object.

Comment: Is your Model.Contact property null?

Comment: How do I check? The Model.Id is null

Comment: You could either check the property in your controller action, or in your view you could do a quick @(Model.Contact == null)

Comment: Basically, your view should be checking that its model is null or not, and then rendering accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:
"In the Form, on the line , it is giving a NullReferenceException that the object reference is not set to the instance of an object."

MVC3 requires that you use the Html Helper to pass input as it adds some additional markup.

```
@Html.Hidden("currentId", @Model.Id)
```

And then in your [HttpPost] controller

```
public ActionResult someController(int currentId)
{
    //Use current Id
    return RedirectToAction("responseController");
}
```