# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'yyyy', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'xx'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two model and I want to show in one view. So I'm using

```
 @Html.Partial
```

This is my first Model.

```
public partial class graduandModel :BaseNopEntityModel 
    {

        public graduandModel()
        {
            this.AvailableCeremony = new List<SelectListItem>();

        }


        public string first_name { get; set; }

        public string middle_name { get; set; }

        public string last_name { get; set; }

        public int student_id { get; set; }

        public int ceremony_id { get; set; }

        public DateTime ceremony_date { get; set; }

        public int graduand_id { get; set; }

        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCeremony { get; set; }

        public graduandDegreeModel graduandDegreeGroup { get; set; }

    }
```

This is my second Model.

```
 public class graduandDegreeModel
    {

        public graduandDegreeModel()
        {
            this.AvailableDegree = new List<SelectListItem>();

        }

        public  string degree_id { get; set; }
        public  int graduand_id { get; set; }

        public  string degree_name { get; set; }

        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableDegree { get; set; }

    }
```

This is mu controller

```
public ActionResult CheckData(int ceremony_id, string first_name, string middle_name, string last_name)
        {
          graduandModel model = new graduandModel();

             graduandDegreeModel model_1 = new graduandDegreeModel();
             var graduandList = _graduandService.GetGraduandByStudent(ceremony_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name);             

               if (graduandList.Count != 0)
               {
                   model.ceremony_id = ceremony_id;
                   model.first_name = first_name;
                   model.middle_name = middle_name;
                   model.last_name = last_name;

                  // var degreeList = "";

                   foreach (var c in graduandList)
                   {

                       var degreeList = _graduandDegreeService.getAllDegreeIdBtGraduandId(c.graduand_id);

                       foreach (var d in degreeList)
                       {
                           model_1.AvailableDegree.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = d.Degree.degree_name, Value = d.degree_id });
                       }
                   }
               }
               return View(model);           

        }
```

This is my views

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsThree.cshtml";
}



@model graduandModel
@using Nop.Web.Models.Hire;
@using Nop.Web.Framework;
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using System.Linq;

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 { 
<table  >

 <tr>
    <td >
      Ceremony : 
    </td>
    <td>
       Ceremony at @Model.ceremony_date

    </td>
</tr>

  <tr>
            <td >
              Name :
            </td>
            <td >
               @Model.first_name  @Model.middle_name  @Model.last_name
            </td>
        </tr>



</table>

     <div>


          @Html.Partial("_DegreeDetailsByGraduand", Model.graduandDegreeGroup)


     </div>
 }
```

This is my  Partial view

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsThree.cshtml";
}



@model graduandDegreeModel
@using Nop.Web.Models.Hire;
@using Nop.Web.Framework;
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using System.Linq;


<table  >

 <tr>
    <td >
      AAAAAA
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.degree_id, Model.AvailableDegree)
       @* @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ceremony_id)*@
    </td>
</tr>



</table>
```

there is error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Nop.Web.Models.Hire.graduandModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Nop.Web.Models.Hire.graduandDegreeModel'.
```

How can I slove it???

Comment: Am I just missing it? I don't see where graduandModel.graduandDegreeGroup gets set (which would mean it is null)

Comment: public graduandDegreeModel graduandDegreeGroup { get; set; } This one is under the graduandModel

Comment: Your controller action CheckData isn't actually setting the graduandDegreeGroup - since it's null you're passing null to the @Html.Partial helper.  So instead of using the overload of (partialViewName, model), it's using Partial(partialViewName) and sending on your main model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option for you may be to create a new view model which combines the two models above into one.  That way it has properties for all of the data you require for this view.  Then you don't need to specify a model in your call to the partial view, it will automatically use the parent's model.  Alternatively, you may not need to separate the view into partials at all with the use of a combined model.  It is not uncommon to have a unique view model for each different view.  In some applications, it can be rare that two different views require the same data.

The combined view model:

```
public class CheckDataViewModel 
    {
        public CheckDataViewModel ()
        {
            this.AvailableCeremony = new List<SelectListItem>();
            this.AvailableDegree = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string middle_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public int student_id { get; set; }
        public int ceremony_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime ceremony_date { get; set; }
        public int graduand_id { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCeremony { get; set; }
        public graduandDegreeModel graduandDegreeGroup { get; set; }
        public  string degree_id { get; set; }
        public  string degree_name { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableDegree { get; set; }
    }
```

The combined view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsThree.cshtml";
}



@model CheckDataViewModel
@using Nop.Web.Models.Hire;
@using Nop.Web.Framework;
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using System.Linq;

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 { 
<table  >

 <tr>
    <td >
      Ceremony : 
    </td>
    <td>
       Ceremony at @Model.ceremony_date

    </td>
</tr>

  <tr>
            <td >
              Name :
            </td>
            <td >
               @Model.first_name  @Model.middle_name  @Model.last_name
            </td>
        </tr>



</table>

     <div>


         <table  >

 <tr>
    <td >
      AAAAAA
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.degree_id, Model.AvailableDegree)
       @* @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ceremony_id)*@
    </td>
</tr>



</table>


     </div>
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't create an instance for graduandModel's graduandDegreeGroup property. So this line:

`@Html.Partial("_DegreeDetailsByGraduand", Model.graduandDegreeGroup)`

will throw an exception like you said. Simply because the second parameter is NULL.

You can try to modify graduandModel's constructor as below:

```
    public graduandModel()
    {
        this.AvailableCeremony = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.graduandDegreeGroup = new graduandDegreeModel();

    }
```

The exception should be gone.
You may also find this link helpful: [ASP.NET MVC renderpartial, model item passed into the dictionary is of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480031/asp-net-mvc-renderpartial-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type)